# I cannot find a decent markdown editor that supports google drive

Tags: google-drive, markdown

I really like to use Markdown, it is MUCH faster than fighting stupid word processing software (be it Word, Google Docs, Libre Office... all of them are mostly terrible)

Except... Seemly noone supports it :( I am currently editing it using Sublime Text while saving the files in a Google Drive Desktop folder.

The problem is that the other people in my company just ignore them, and instead rely on google docs exported versions, and make edits there, since I am in charge of the documents I have then to backport all changes to markdown, it is really annoying (also: as other people edit the google docs versions, the formatting get VERY messy, proving that allowing people to use google docs is NOT good idea)

I tried dillinger, but it fails to find .md files, I dunno why (also, why only .md? all my files before dillinger I named them .mdown)

Also I tried StackEdit but it can only see one google drive at once, and do not let me choose what one I want, and its default is terrible (my personal account, instead the company account). Also StackEdit color scheme is terrible and seemly I cannot change it.

Someone here know something else that can help?

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of StackEdit. StackEdit supports multiple documents in one window. You can use the document panel (button on the top right corner) or Ctrl+[ or Ctrl+] to switch from one document to another. The color scheme can be changed in Settings->Themes. Regarding management of multiple Google accounts there is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/111).

Comment: StackEdit now supports multiple Google Drive accounts. Just set the number of accounts you have in Settings->Services->Google Drive multi-accounts. You will see new items in the left menu  (2nd account, 3rd account).

Comment: I found the theme, but not the multi account setting. (and I am pretty sure I found the services tab in the settings menu).

Comment: Can you check that you are running version 3.1 in Menu->About? If not you probably have to clear your browser's application cache (chrome://appcache-internals/ for chrome). It should be automatically refreshed while browsing the page though.

Comment: Alright, finally I figured how to reload it (using control+shift+r on google chrome)

Except now it freezes the browser tab instead, as soon it loads.

By the way, that is on a OSX, Google Chrome

Comment: Weird. Can you open a ticket on GitHub? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

[Neutron64](https://www.neutron64.com/) (formerly Neutron Drive) supports Markdown and Auto saves to Google Drive. Neutron64 functions like a web application. You can code in your browser with Google Drive or your private cloud server. The Basic Edition of Neutron64 costs $8.00/year subscription or pay with your CPU.